# To store certain keys on the same Couchbase node in a cluster

Tags: couchbase

Is it possible to make sure that certain keys get stored on the same Couchbase node in a cluster? Say there's User and its Preferences (not a real example, just for sake of simplicity here...) and most the time I will get them together to display on a page. Thought it would be natural to place them on the same node so the client does not retrieve it from different nodes.

How should I name the keys to make sure they place on the same node? Is it possible at all? Is it something I should care about ever?

Comment: Why would you want to take away sharding and availability management from CB and have it on application side - managing HA on your own? That is one of the benefits using Couchbase - out of the box. Do you have some particular performance issues? I think Couchbase's vBucket concept is a robust solution for production. You can read up on vBucket: http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/Concepts/concept-vBucket.html

Comment: That is the article that raised my question actually. I thought that both entries might reside in different vBuckets so the client would need to fetch the first one from vBucket-A and another one from vBucketB... thought I would name the two keys in some way to make sure they live in the same vBucket... say they both start with "user:" prefix or something. I do not have particular performance issue though, just looking around and grasping CB concepts.

Comment: But even if you were to somehow "full" key sharding algorithm to place all keys in your logical group into one vBucket...I see several problems arise: 1. vBucket size might be too small for your groups of keys/values that you plan to keep in one vBucket. 2. CB replication has to be enabled anyway, since you want fail-over in case server instance goes down...then shadow instance should take over.. the point #2 actually implies that you have to use CB's HA mechanism.

Comment: Another alternative, you could have only one "master" key and store all your other sub keys and its values as a value document under master key...you will not have this problem anymore

Answer (score 2):

While it is technically possible, and there are cases such as your example in which it would seem logical to do so, there is little benefit, particularly when contrasted with the potential drawbacks that ensuring keys do go to the intended nodes.

To justify the 'little benefit' comment, for a typical system in good health, there should be minimal discrepancies between nodes in terms of time taken to access any particular document (be it the time it takes for a node to retrieve a document or the time taken to send that document over a network), and as such any performance gain that would occur due to grouping keys on a node would be marginal.

The other main area of interest, would be availability. Benefit here could be greater, as if one node goes down for whatever reason, there's the chance that the node isn't the one containing all the linked keys and hence one of the remaining nodes will be enough to sustain (a particular part of) a system. There is also, however, the risk that the one node containing all the *priority* keys will go down, leaving no active keys for the system, and requiring (auto)failover or [replica reads](http://docs.couchbase.com/developer/dev-guide-3.0/replica-read-functions.html). However, even with these keys distributed across a node, the same availability will be afforded with the same (auto)failover and replica read mechanisms, leaving minimal (if any) benefit.

The drawbacks are far greater, however, as the means of ensuring keys get sent to particular nodes will require modification of the hashing algorithm used to shard the keys, which would require thorough testing and design before reliably deploying to a development cluster.

Answer (score 0):

This question is pretty old but I have the same question with regarding Counchbase so I add some comments.

Redis cluster has the exact feature you asked where part of the key that is wrapped using {} will be used to calculate the hash instead of the whole key.

Below is one case this could be useful.

Let's say a cluster of Couchbase or Redis nodes is used to save session data for 20+ web servers. If one web server's data always goes to the same node, then even part of the cluster is down and can't be recovered, only the web servers the node serves would be impacted. Otherwise, all web servers will be down.